# MongoDB: how to find documents of same type with min value and $lt value

Tags: mongodb

I have the following docs in collection:

```
{'type': 1, 'price': 150, 'quantity': 10}
{'type': 1, 'price': 90, 'quantity': 5}

{'type': 2, 'price': 150, 'quantity': 10}
{'type': 2, 'price': 90, 'quantity': 10}
{'type': 2, 'price': 100, 'quantity': 5}
```

How could i find a doc of each type with min price and quantity lower than 10?

i need to query and get:

```
{'type': 1, 'price': 90, 'quantity': 5}
{'type': 2, 'price': 100, 'quantity': 5}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pipeline:

1. Match document with a quantity lower than 10.
2. Group the first document by type.
3. Deconstructs the docs array
4. Replace its root.

.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "quantity": {
        "$lt": 10
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$type",
      "docs": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$docs"
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "price": 100,
    "quantity": 5,
    "type": 2
  },
  {
    "price": 90,
    "quantity": 5,
    "type": 1
  }
]
```